# Power BI Web Source Wont Update through Gateway

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I have an API source I am using on a report. It works fine on my Desktop, and I added the URL and Basic Login credentials to my Gateway. I get an error that my source is unable to update, but I don't know why. When I test the connection in my Gateway it says it connects fine. For some reason my published data set doesn't recognize the report's source as the same one as the one in my gateway.

**Is there any additional step required in publishing a Web Data Source in order to make it use the gateway's web source?**

**This is the Error I get:**
[image: This is the Error I get]

**This is the Gateway's connection to the API:**
[image: This is the Gateway's connection to the API]

**This is the (Much Truncated) version of the Query I am using to retrieve the data:**

```
let 
    Url = "https://rest.avatax.com/api/v2/companies/XXXX/transactions/",
    RawData = Web.Contents(Url),
    Json    = Json.Document(RawData)
in  
    Json
```

Comment: I know it sounds dumb, have you tried making Web.Contents the first line of the query? I don't yet have personal experience with an on-prem gateway, but based on the message it sounds like it's not reading it as a valid "type" of query to refresh. Web queries are on the list of valid connections for scheduled refresh using a gateway, so maybe it needs to be the first line of the query for it read as a "Web" connection?

Comment: @Wedge, good thought! I did try it, but no luck. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an incredibly annoying "feature", but the Power BI service does a different code analysis than Power BI Desktop. The way to overcome it is to present a static URL like this:

```
let 
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://rest.avatax.com/api/v2/companies/XXXX/transactions/"))
in  
    Source
```

Chris Webb described this in more detail (along with hacks to make the URL dynamic) in this blog post:

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/08/23/web-contents-m-functions-and-dataset-refresh-errors-in-power-bi/

Comment: seems promising, I'll test it out

Comment: that worked. Making the URL as a string in Web.Contents() allowed it to work. Then I was able to add dynamic values to the Query[] array via a parameterized function.